# Problem in include path and oistream error

Tags: c++

Please help me when I write any code in c++ then following error is detected
1.#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (F:\Run\Ram).
2.cannot open source file "oistream"

VS Code version: Code 1.48.1 (3dd9051, 2020-08-19T17:12:39.269Z)
OS version: Windows_NT ia32 6.1.7601

[image: include oistream]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to c++ :)). The problem is that the library is called "iostream" and NOT "oistream". It might help to think of it as "input/output stream".